# Check element in list of lists from items in another list of lists

Tags: python, list, for-loop

I have one list of lists `list1` and one list to check `list2` that I'd like to run a for loop to check if elements from `list2` are in `list1`, then append the element present to 'models' which is a list that pulls the first index from each list in `list1`.

No errors but I believe it might be because of the types I'm working with.

My code:

```
a = "sample.txt"  # Contains multiple rows like "model1//h//4385////ffm1//gg5////lmm"

file1 = open(a, "r")
with open(a, 'r') as file:
    lines = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in file]

cleaned_data = []
def split_lines(lines, delimiter, remove='^[0-9.]+$'):
    for line in lines:
        tokens = line.split(delimiter)
        tokens = [re.sub(remove, "", token) for token in tokens]
        clean_list = list(filter(lambda e: e.strip(), tokens))
        cleaned_data.append(clean_list)

split_lines(lines, "/")
print(cleaned_data)
# outputs: ["model1", "h", "ffm1", "gg5", "1mm"] for each line in txt

##cleaned_data = [["model1", "h", "ffm1", "gg5", "1mm"], then more of this
## in a list of lists

list2 = ['gg5', 'pp6', 'gg7']  # to check element in the cleaned_data

models = []
for item in cleaned_data:
    if item[0] not in models:
        models.append(item[0])
##  models = ['model1', 'model2', 'model3']

for item in cleaned_data:
    if item == insulation:
        models.append(item)
print(models)

#This is where I want to check if elements in list2 are in the list of lists #in cleaned_data, then append that elements from list2 to index1 of models.
```

Output:

```
['model1', 'model2', 'model3']
```

Expected output:

```
[['model1', 'gg5'], ['model2', 'pp6'], ['model3', 'gg5']
```

Comment: the more I read the more I don't understand: from the title there should be 2 nested sublists, one is `cleaned_data` and the other one? Where is from `list2`? What is the classification rule? I would be helpful to have a input/output description

Answer (score 1):

There are some issues with your code.

Your loop doesn't do anything, because when you do:

```py
if item == list2:
```

The comparison will always be false, as the structure of `item` and `list2` are different (e.g. you're comparing `["model1", "yes", "TT42"]` with `['TT42', 'GG50', 'BB12']`).

Your output is `['model1', model2', 'model3']` but it is because you defined it as such, the loop didn't change it.

Also, when you do:

```py
models.append(item)
```

You were going to add a whole list inside the `models` variable. For instance, if the first comparison of the loop was correct, you'd have:

```py
>>> print(models)
['model1', model2', 'model3', ['model1', 'yes', 'TT42']]
```

And it's obviously not what you want.

---

Here's a way of doing what you want:

```py
list1 = [['model1', 'yes', 'TT42'], 
        ['model2', 'yes', 'GG50'],
        ['model3', 'no', 'BB12']]

list2 = ['TT42', 'GG50', 'BB12']
models = [[item[0], item[2]] for item in list1 if item[2] in list2]
```

Output:

```py
>>> print(models)
[['model1', 'TT42'], ['model2', 'GG50'], ['model3', 'BB12']]
```

Comment: I checked the types of my list1 and list2 to ensure they are lists. But this script just returns `[]` when I print models.

Comment: This works by itself, but if I change `list1` to my source data it just outputs `[]`. My source data is a list of lists like the example.

Comment: Could it be that I'm running ```models = []
for item in cleaned_data:
    if item[0] not in models:
        models.append(item[0])``` before?

Comment: @Chaotic.Python Running this snippet shouldn't change anything, since you overwrite it anyways with my list comprehension. In my opinion, your `list1` isn't a correct minimal representation of your source data, could you paste a part of your source data in the original post? And if your `list2` is an example too here, give it as well.

Comment: I edited the code to include more detail, hoping this will help!

Answer (score 0):

IIUC this will take your list 2 and compare it to your list 1 and find where all anything from list2 is equal to anything from list1 and add it to the models list

```
list1 = [['model1', 'yes', 'TT42'], 
        ['model2', 'yes', 'GG50'],
        ['model3', 'no', 'BB12']]

list2 = ['TT42', 'GG50', 'BB12']

single_list = [list1[x][y] for x in range(0, len(list1)) for y in range(0, len(list1[x]))]

models = [x for x in list2 for y in single_list if x ==y]
models
```

If this is not the expected results please provide more details and expected results.

Comment: I checked the types of my list1 and list2 to ensure they are lists. But this script just returns `[]` when I print models.

Comment: Does the code I provided work on your computer? If it does can you provide more details for you data as that should work based on the provided code

Comment: The code itself works, when I run it solely it returns `['TT42', 'GG50', 'BB12']`.

Comment: My expected output would be to append the elements from list2 into `models', so I have a list of lists that equate to `[model, element], [model, element], [model, element].

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand correctly, but does this produce what you want?:

```
list1 = [["model1", "h", "ffm1", "gg5", "1mm"], 
    ["model2", "h", "ffm1", "pp6", "1mm"],
    ["model2", "h", "ffm1", "gg7", "1mm"]]

list2 = ['gg5', 'pp6', 'gg7']
models=[]

for x in list2:
    for y in list1:
        if x in y[1:]:
            models.append([y[0],x])
```

---

Also, this is another way I could think of:

```
cleaned_data = [["model1", "h", "ffm1", "gg5", "1mm"], 
    ["model2", "h", "ffm1", "pp6", "1mm"],
    ["model2", "h", "ffm1", "gg7", "1mm"]]

list2 = ['gg5', 'pp6', 'gg7']
models = {}
for item in cleaned_data:
    if item[0] not in models:
        models[item[0]]=[] 
for x in list2:
    for y in list1:
        if x in y[1:]:
            models[y[0]].append(x)

result=[[item[0],*item[1]] for item in models.items()]

# result: [['model1', 'gg5'], ['model2', 'pp6', 'gg7']]
```

Answer (score 0):

For each row, you can extract the first column as the model name and the rest as properties, and obtain the property that matches any item in `list2` by performing a set intersection with `list2`, which, for efficiency, should be converted to a set in advance:

```
set2 = set(list2)
models = [[model, prop] for model, *props in list1 for prop in set2.intersection(props)]
```

Demo: https://replit.com/@blhsing/FakeFaintVendors